# Android push message issue, getting old message always on display screen

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging

please help me out. I am stuck with GCM push message.
Everything working perfect but when I am trying to display my message on next screen I am getting always old one or first one.
But If I check my log cat, I am getting new message always from the server. So where is problem I am not getting. I have tried many code on stackoverflow. Here is the snippet of my code-

```
// this is the my service class
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

// this is the onMessage revive method 
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        generateNotification(context, message);
        System.out.println(message+"++++++++++1");
    }

// this is the notification method

private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        System.out.println(message+"++++++++++2");
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        String subTitle = "Important News for you!";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("content", message);

        //PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

        PendingIntent intent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
        //To play the default sound with your notification:
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

public class NotificationView extends Activity {
    // and this is the my next activity where i am displaying push message-
    Intent intent=getIntent();
                    stringValue=intent.getStringExtra("content");

                    System.out.println(stringValue);
```

I have already try-

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

and this-
PendingIntent intent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Both did not work for me.

Comment: System.out.println(message+"++++++++++1"); and
 System.out.println(message+"++++++++++2"); is give me correct messages. But on next page I am getting old only.

Comment: And same code is working fine for me in another application.

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine ,Try using String Buffer may because String Data cant be change unless new is specified every time im new here give me vote up :)

Comment: where I am using string?

Comment: private void generateNotification(Context context, String message)

Comment: but below that i am getting right message-
 System.out.println(message+"++++++++++2")

Comment: here is the link-
http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/google-cloud-messaging-example-in.html